# OOP pygame movement issues

Tags: python, oop, input, pygame

I am just getting started with pygame. My Player instances position does not update on the surface even though it's x value is changed accordingly.

```
'''__main__.py'''
import script

if __name__ == '__main__':
    script.setup()
    script.update()
```

-

```
'''script.py'''
import pygame
from player import Player
from enemy import Enemy
from ball import Ball


def setup():
    global window, player, enemy, ball

    pygame.init()
    pygame.display.set_caption('Pong')
    window = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

    player = Player(40, window.get_height() / 2 - 100 / 2, 20, 100)
    enemy = Enemy(window.get_width() - 40 - 20, window.get_height() / 2 - 100 / 2, 20, 100)


def draw():
    player.update()
    enemy.update()
    pygame.display.update()

    player.draw(window)
    enemy.draw(window)

def update():

    running = True
    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False


        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            player.up = True
        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            player.down = True

        if not keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            player.up = False
        if not keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            player.down = False

        draw()


    pygame.quit()
```

-

```
'''player.py'''
import pygame

class Player:
    '''Player'''
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.color = (255, 255, 255)
        self.rect = (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)
        self.vel = 10
        self.up = False
        self.down = False

    def draw(self, surface):
        pygame.draw.rect(surface, self.color, self.rect)

    def update(self):
        if self.up:
            self.x -= self.vel
        if self.down:
            self.x += self.vel
```

The instance's x value changes when I press up or down, but for some reason it does not get drawn on screen. I have tried moving the draw method and the player.update method but can't seem to get it to work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the `Player.draw` method. It draws using `self.rect`.

The problem with your `update` method is that it never updates `self.rect`. So `self.rect` stays the same as after constructor.

Remove `self.rect` as attribute and replace it with either simple method (Option A) or property (Option B):

```py
class Player:
    # Options A:
    def get_rect(self):
        return (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)

    # Option B:
    @property
    def rect(self):
        return (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)
```

Or update `self.rect` inside `update` method. But I do not recommend that. Having it separately was a reason why you got your no-changing-position-bug in the first place.